# How to connect and send file to MongoDb with angular file upload

Tags: mongodb, angular-file-upload

I am trying to upload file, i am using "Angular File Upload" for it. Trying to connect and send file to mongodb but it gives this error on firebug

**net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE**

In mongodb.log log files it shows the connection is done:

**2014-11-09T11:57:05.512+0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from xxx.x.x.x:53749 #2 (1 connection now open)**

**2014-11-09T11:57:05.524+0400 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection xxx.x.x.x:53749 (0 connections now open)**

I have also create and used ssl certificate.

My Angular Js code is:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {        

    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.    
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {    
      var $file = $files[i];    
      $upload.upload({          

        url: "https://localhost:27017/mydb",    
        file: $file,    
        progress: function(e){  console.log("Progress: ");}

      }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {    
        // file is uploaded successfully    
        console.log("File Uploaded : "+ data);    
      });    
    }


  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an interim step there. Going directly from Angular to Mongo will not work out. If you want a generic REST interface to Mongo with which you can utilize Angular's bundled $http services, take a look at the list of REST services on Mongo's site.

Mongo REST Services

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface#HttpInterface-RESTInterfaces

Angular $http Service:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

There's a lot of different options here, but this is likely the easiest way to get up and going.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:3000/database');
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    routeFrom : String,
    routeTo : String,
    leaving: String
});
var Order = db.model('Order', orderSchema);
module.exports = Order;
```